# Azure customscript extension from bitbucket pipeline not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am using azure-vm-linux-script-deploy pipe to perform some actions on target machine. This pipe internally uses azure custom script.

**az vm extension set --resource-group myresourecegroup --vm-name my-vm-test --name CustomScript --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions --version 2.0 --verbose --protected-settings protected-settings.json --force-update**

This pipe failing with "Invalid configuration for custom command" error

**ERROR: Deployment failed. VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'hostname'. Error message: "Enable failed: failed to get configuration: invalid configuration: 'commandToExecute' was specified both in public and protected settings; it must be specified only once".**

**Pipe looks like this:**

```
      - pipe: microsoft/azure-vm-linux-script-deploy:1.0.1
        variables:
          AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
          AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
          AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
          AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: $AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP
          AZURE_VM_NAME: $AZURE_VM_NAME
          AZURE_EXTENSION_COMMAND: 'bash setup_script.sh'
          AZURE_EXTENSION_FILES: 'setup_script.sh'
          AZURE_FORCE_UPDATE: 'true'
          AZURE_NO_WAIT: 'false'
          AZURE_CLEANUP: 'true'
```

Comment: how about looking into the error its displaying? you pass in the commandToExecute two times somehow

Comment: logs shows only this error.